# How to debug Ember data's find in the console

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18595208/733034), I learned that I can use `find` in the console. But I'm having some problems using this to look up the data in my [litte jsbin Ember.js with Ember Data and LSAdapter App here](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/469).

1. Please add some orgs
2. Please open your chrome console to see more details.
3. Please type in `App.container.lookup('store:main').find('org').toArray()` **Why does it show an empty array**???

Thank you so much for helping out

Answer (score 18):

It's because find returns promises now

```
App.__container__.lookup('store:main').find('org').then(function(stuff){console.log(stuff.toArray())});
```

You can see that find is a promise when you do

```
> App.__container__.lookup('store:main').find('org').toString();

"<DS.PromiseArray:ember355>"
```

Comment: FWIW, you can get to the store without going thru the container. `App.Org.store.find('org').then( function(result) { console.log(result.getEach('name').toString()); });`

Comment: Mike, you're right. Why doesn't the [ember data transition document](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md) say that we can do `App.Model.store.find`? All the examples they have are `this.store.find`.  So how did you find out about this trick?

Comment: Honestly I just guessed. Accessing the store via a global like App.Model.store is not a good idea except from console. I bet the ember docs avoid mentioning it on purpose to avoid confusing people. `this.store.find` is definitely the way to go in your application code.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea? I was first thinking it was a better idea because it was similar to the previous version's style `App.Model.blah`, and it can be used anywhere. Just curious.

Comment: Hard to answer that in a comment. Ember framework has strong opinions about when/where to do things. For example, route or controller should be calling Model.find not the view. Framework will make objects available locally in the right places. So if a local `store` property isn't available that's a hint from framework that you're doing it wrong. Using global variable like App.Model makes it too easy to paint yourself into a corner. Also working with local references makes code less brittle and much easier to test in isolation.