# How to find model with Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What's the equivalent of

```
App.Person.find({age: 30})
```

in the [new Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md)?

I.e. how do I get an record array based on an attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent method in ember data 1.0.0 beta2 is now:

```
this.store.find('person', {age: 30})
```

More info on all the changes can be found [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md).

Hope it helps.

Comment: If it were only JUST for mentioning which version you were using...
I'd still upvote you. You magnificent being.

Answer (score 8):

There are actually a couple ways of doing this.  In this example, the model is "Org", the parameter is all org names with name "AAA":

```
this.store.find('org', {'name' : 'AAA'})
```

Or

```
App.Org.store.find('org', {'name' : 'AAA'})
```

They would both return the same Ember Promise Array.

To work with individual elements in the array you can do:

```
this.store.find('org', {'name' : 'AAA'}).then( function(result) {
     // do stuff with each result
});
```

Similarly,

```
App.Org.store.find('org', {'name' : 'AAA'}).then( function(result) {
     // do stuff with each result
});
```

[Everything here and more is shown in this jsbin, so you can compare and play yourself.](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/471) Don't forget to see the results by opening the console.

Thanks to [Mike's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18753178/733034).