# How to do filter in the new Ember Data? Also how does filter compare to find in the new Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What's the equivalent of

```
App.Person.filter(function(e){return e.get('age') == 30})
```

in the [new Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md)?

---

In the old Ember Data, `App.Model.filter` produced a different type of object versus `App.Model.find` ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18756092/733034)). I discovered the type difference because if I wanted the record itself and make changes, I had to use `filter`. So `find` was kind of like read-only. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Is it the case in the new Ember Data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the new Ember Data (Beta 1.0.0) you can use the `filter` function from the `DS.Store` [class](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter). Unlike the previous `filter` function of the Model, you have to specify the type of Model you want:

```
this.get('store').filter('person', function(record){return record.get('age') == 30});
```