# Ember Data: Get a Model in the Console

Tags: javascript, ember.js, console, ember-data

I have the simplest possible Ember app in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aYIkAcUk/2/edit). All I'm trying to do is find a model. Based on other [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756092/how-to-find-model-with-ember-data/18768501#18768501), I've tried the following.

```
App.User.get('store').find('user', 1);
App.User.Store.find('user', 1);
```

I've defined `App.Store`, but `App.Store` returns `undefined` in the console. I'm obviously missing the absolute most basic concepts of Ember models. Explain like I'm 5, please? I literally just want to return a `user` object and call a property on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The store is injected to routes/controllers.  Inside a route/controller you can use `this.store.find('user', 1)` to fetch a model.  But there is no global access to the store.

http://jsbin.com/aYIkAcUk/6/edit

**If you feel guilty about touching the innards, which you should a bit, do not read on.**

For transparency sake, you can get the store globally.  After the application has initialized and is ready you can use the innards of ember to fetch it using the container lookup method.  (If you need to know when the app is ready you can use the application `ready` hook.

```
 var store = App.__container__.lookup('store:main');
 var user = store.find('user', 1);
```

http://jsbin.com/aYIkAcUk/7/edit

Comment: I know Ember Data is changing all the time, and this tutorial is a few months old, but [here](http://matthewlehner.net/ember-js-routing-and-views/)'s where I saw an example of just getting a user in the console. Does Ember Data not support this anymore?

Comment: That's pretty out of date.  https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Answer (score 9):

As of Ember Data 2, the data store is now handled as a service. Thus, to look it up globally, the statement is now:

```
App.__container__.lookup('service:store')
```

Where `App` is the name of your Ember application. Kingpin2k's answer will not work with Ember Data 2.

Comment: Finally, an up-to-date info. Thank you! This should be the new accepted answer.